# Response Body Key Path and HTTP Exchanges history size

Tags: paw-app

I have a REST web service that will issue a `LogonToken` when you authenticate. All subsequent REST calls require that `LogonToken` to be passed in the header as `X-SAP-LogonToken`.

I've used the [Response Body Key Path](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/dynamic-values/response%23Response_Body_Key_Path) in Paw to insert the `LogonToken` retrieved in the first REST call in all other REST calls' headers. This works fine, except for one caveat. At some point, the response body history of the initial authentication call will be removed, depending on the *HTTP Exchanges in History setting*.

[image: HTTP Exchanges in History]

One obvious solution (workaround?) is to set the value of this setting very high, but this has implications on the performance / resource usage of the app in general, and at one point, the limit will still be reached and the response body will be removed.

Ideally, you should be able to either set the HTTP Exchange limit per request, instead of globally, or have a setting that keeps the response body of a given request from being purged.

While I can easily generate a new `LogonToken` by executing the initial REST call again, the problem is that this will give me a new session on the server, and whatever actions I've taken in the previous session will be lost (as I don't know nor saved the value of the initial `LogonToken`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sorry for the very late answer!* The default value of the "HTTP Exchanges in History" preference is 300. As of the latest version of Paw, this number isn't causing any performance hit (as it was the case in some older version of Paw). So you should be safe setting this again to a much higher limit (a few hundred).

To give you some insight, Paw now stores large data blobs in external files, so even with larger requests/responses, the performance should be fine.

About the "Response Body Key Path", yes this obviously relies on the history…so if a response has been wiped out from the History, then it won't be available for this dynamic value.